# encryption using key for base32 in AES

Tags: ios, encryption, aes

I need to use a key with which i can encrypt data using base32 (AES)in IOS.I was able to successfully do the same with base64 in AES . In AES with base64 i can use a key with which the data get encryped.I can be decrypted using the same key

Comment: Show some code so we can get a better idea of what your are trying to accomplish. the words "base64 in AES" are confusing, please explain.

Answer (score 1):

AES encrypts byte arrays (or `NSData` in iOS). Sometimes crypto libraries have convenience methods that encode/decode to base 64, but the underlying encryption is always on bytes.

Base32 is not as common, so encrypting/decrypting Base32 is not likely to be supported by any convenience method within the libraries. You will have to perform the encoding/decoding to base32 yourself. Base32 and base64 encoding is key-less, so you should be able to use the same key, as this will only be used by the AES encryption/decryption itself.